# Haskell namespace when reexporting

Tags: haskell, module, export

I am not sure how the namespace works in the following case :

[Data.Streaming.Network](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-commons-0.1.12.1/docs/src/Data-Streaming-Network.html) reexports HostPreference from  [Data.Streaming.Network.Internal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-commons-0.1.12.1/docs/src/Data-Streaming-Network-Internal.html#HostPreference)

When I load up in ghci, I can see that the constructors are prefixed by the original namespace.

```
$ ghci                                                          
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import Data.Streaming.Network
Prelude Data.Streaming.Network> :info HostPreference
data HostPreference
  = Data.Streaming.Network.Internal.HostAny
  | Data.Streaming.Network.Internal.HostIPv4
  | Data.Streaming.Network.Internal.HostIPv4Only
  | Data.Streaming.Network.Internal.HostIPv6
  | Data.Streaming.Network.Internal.HostIPv6Only
  | Data.Streaming.Network.Internal.Host String
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Streaming.Network.Internal’
```

But some program expect the bindings for the constructors to be available under the reexporting module Data.Streaming.Network.

```
Prelude Data.Streaming.Network> :l src/Server.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Server.hs, interpreted )

src/Server.hs:14:58: Not in scope: data constructor ‘HostAny’
```

What is going on, who is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructors for `HostPreference` are not exported, the `streaming-commons` package intends for them to be private, if I am to judge by what is exported.  Instead, the documentation suggests using `OverloadedStrings` and typing string literals to get the different values:

> `data HostPreference`
>
> Which host to bind.
>
> Note: The `IsString` instance recognizes the following special values:
>
> `*` means `HostAny`
>
> `*4` means `HostIPv4`
>
> `!4` means `HostIPv4Only`
>
> `*6` means `HostIPv6`
>
> `!6` means `HostIPv6Only`
>
> Any other values is treated as a hostname. As an example, to bind to the IPv4 local host only, use `"127.0.0.1"`.

So in your `Server.hs`, just enable `OverloadedStrings` and then where ever you're trying to use `HostAny` just type `"*"` instead.